# Mongodb text Search with Search words with Negated Term

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, spring-data-mongodb

This is how the logic should work

Search names: Ram, David, Lakshman

Negated names: Ram

Search has the following names

Ram Kumar

Ram Lakshman

David Kumar

---

The Search result should be :

Ram Lakshman

David Kumar

---

Performed the text search query with exclusions:
db.names.find({ $text: { $search: "Ram David Lakshman -Ram"} });

The Search result has only 1 record

David Kumar

---

My Search Names are around 5000 and exclusions are in 100s and "names" collection in Millions.